# batch file IF condition

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, netsh

I'm trying to get the current active connection with netsh (i'd rather not use wmic) using the following code.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%A IN ('netsh interface show interface^|findstr /i "\<connected\>"') DO (

if %%B == .........
)
```

I only want to account for the default connection names:

Wi-Fi, Ethernet, Wireless Network Connection, Local Area Connection and do something based on that.

eg: if %%B = WiFi or Ethernet or....(

::do something here
)

I only want "something" to be executed once because only 1 of those connections will ever be active at any given time.

Comment: I must say, I'm a little confused, because if you 'only have one active connection ever', what difference does its interface name make? What are you really trying to determine? Or perhaps to put it another way, what exactly are your `if` commands going to do, based upon the returned interface name?

Comment: for some strange reason, netsh shows other "virtual" adapters as active/connected. So i basically need to filter to get the physical connections (they have the default names used in the if statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this ought to do the trick:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=3,*" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface ^| findstr /i "\<connected\>"') do (
    set ifname=%%b
    if "!ifname:~0,8!"=="Ethernet" goto execute
    if "!ifname:~0,21!"=="Local Area Connection" goto execute
    if "!ifname:~0,5!"=="Wi-Fi" goto execute
    if "!ifname:~0,27!"=="Wireless Network Connection" goto execute
)
echo No connected interface found, exiting...
goto :EOF

:execute
echo Found connected interface (%ifname%), executing...
:: do whatever you need
```

Basically the idea is to look for interfaces that begin with those four different strings, then jump to the label that executes whatever it is you want.

[I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that this is likely better to be done in PowerShell nowadays, but…]

Comment: yeah no powershell here.....the code doesnt run. well, it just exits...no error or anything

Comment: What OS are you using that doesn’t have PowerShell? Even XP has PowerShell. The code I wrote works here (Windows 10)… I don’t have any unsupported OS (WinXP, Win7, etc) handy to test with. I suggest you throw some `echo` statements in there and see where it’s going off the rails.

Comment: using windows 10 here as well...i will play around with it and see if i can get it to execute

Comment: Changes made : Insert required `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to allow the altered value of `ifname` to be interpreted within the loop. change `%` to `!` to allow the changed rather than the original value of `ifname` to be accessed.

Comment: Alternative: Nest a third loop `for %%c in ("Ethernet" "Wi-Fi" ...) do echo %%b|find %%c >nul&if not errorlevel 1 goto execute` Add any other target strings to the list, but "quote each string". This will attempt to match `%%b` and if the string *is* found, set `errorlevel` to `0` hence being NOT (1 or greater) and triggering the GOTO

Comment: @james, if this now works for you, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested example, which is supposed to just tell you the interface name of the device associated with your only assigned IP Address.

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Interface) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
For /F Tokens^=4 %%G In ('%__APPDIR__%ROUTE.EXE -4 PRINT 0.0.0.0 ^
 ^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /RC:"0.0.0.0 *0.0.0.0"') Do (Set "InterfaceIP=%%G"
    For /F Tokens^=5* %%H In ('%__APPDIR__%netsh.exe interface IP show route^
 ^|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "%%G"') Do Set "InterfaceName=%%I")
If Not Defined InterfaceIP GoTo :EOF
Set Interface & Pause
```

**[EDIT /]**

Here's a slightly modified version of the example from my comments which uses `ping.exe` instead of `ROUTE.EXE` for returning the IP Address used to determine the Interface Name.

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Interface) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%G In ('^"%__APPDIR__%ping.exe "%COMPUTERNAME%" ^
 -n 1 -4 2^> NUL ^| %__APPDIR__%find.exe /I "%COMPUTERNAME%"^"') Do (
    Set "InterfaceIP=%%G" & For /F Tokens^=5* %%H In ('%__APPDIR__%netsh.exe ^
     interface IP show route ^| %__APPDIR__%find.exe "%%G"'
    ) Do Set "InterfaceName=%%I")
If Not Defined InterfaceIP GoTo :EOF
Set Interface & Pause
```

---

*The last line in both examples just displays the two variables so that you can see them. You'd obviously replace those with the rest of your code.*

Comment: nifty solution, however it doesn't work in cases where there's a static ip set, only DHCP. I need to account for both. I like the approach though. If only it worked in static ip cases.

Comment: Not only was that mentioned or implied in your question @james, and therefore wasn't an answer requirement; can you please explain what the specific reason is for excluding WMI? Or are you happy with WMI, just not with WMIC? and if so why?

Comment: Whenever i run wmic on windows 10 i get an access denied error. I want the solution to be portable across at least windows 7 and windows 10 without having to make any alterations to the OS.

Comment: Well @james, [tag:WMIC] is not restricted by default on [tag:Windows-10], or those below it, so that must be a restriction specific to you. How do you expect us to determine a method which works on any machine with any possible restrictions. What is stopping an Administrative policy from restricting `netsh.exe`? What is the actual purpose of this task? not what is your script supposed to do?

Comment: There's no attitude, I'm explaining to you that your restriction is in the minority, _(it is not the default in a user environment)_, so what is stopping other minority restrictions from preventing your script from working? Also please be aware that it is very unlikely that checking the connections with `if` and `==` will be portable on anything other than PC's using the same locale/language, because I doubt very much that all languages us the same English strings.

Comment: ok, if you ever find the time, i would love to try a solution in wmic. My goal is to get the connected network name regardless of status or static dhcp etc...the first solution works because people hardly change the names, but in the event they do..........

Comment: @james, could you please explain the reason for determining the name given to the interface, especially as anybody can rename it themselves at any time. What are you specifically using the name for? Also, my method above uses `ROUTE.EXE` to get the IP address, and you could simply change that part to `For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%G In ('"("%__APPDIR__%ping.exe" "%COMPUTERNAME%" -n 1 -4 2> NUL || "%__APPDIR__%ping.exe" "%COMPUTERNAME%" -n 1 2> NUL) | "%%__APPDIR__%find.exe" /I "%COMPUTERNAME%""') Do Set "InterfaceIP=%%G"`.

Comment: the purpose of getting the current connection is to use netsh to perform operations such as netsh interface ip set address name = "%%ActiveConnection" 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0

Comment: Okay @james, so you're just simply wanting to automate a process for setting options, such as a static IP etc. Therefore you don't really need the name as long as you can make configuration changes to the only active physical network interface; and you don't really have a need to use `netsh.exe` if another method exists. Out of curiosity, what does this output for you. `"%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe" Path Win32_NetworkAdapter Where "NetConnectionStatus='2' And PhysicalAdapter='True'" Get NetConnectionID`?

Comment: NetConnectionID
Wi-Fi
VirtualBox Host-Only Network   .......so i need a way to get only WIFI

Comment: @james, you told us all in your question itself, "only 1 of those connections will ever be active at any given time", but you've just provided output showing that you have two connected physical adapters!

Comment: that was caused by my virtual machine. I have it sorted now however. Thank you very much for all the help @ campo

Comment: So to be clear @james, now that you've disabled the VM NIC, the `WMIC` command I provided is giving you the exact Interface Name string you were looking for.

Comment: that is correct @campo, so did the original netsh. However, your persistence lead me to evaluate why in fact there was more than 1 interface active.